# How to check there are no html files in current directory?

Tags: bash, script

I have a script which will download `html` files into current directory.
Then it'll generate a report based on these `html` files.
At last, it'll delete all these `html` files.
So, when I run this script, I want to make sure there is no `html` files in current dir.

This is what I got:

```
if ls *.html >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo 'clear HTML files first'
    exit
fi
```

Is there any easy way to check?

Comment: Your example should work if you want no folders, symbolic links, etc. named `*.html` either.

Comment: Why not creating a temporary directory with `mktemp -d` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *failglob* option; checks for any matches:

```
if (shopt -s failglob; true *.html) 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Found files"
fi
```

Using *nullglob* and arrays; counts the files:

```
numfiles=$( shopt -s nullglob; files=(*.html); echo ${#files[@]} )

if (( numfiles > 0 )); then
    echo "Have $numfiles HTML files"
else
    echo "No files"
fi
```

Another way, without using *nullglob* or discarding `$files`:

```
files=(*.html)
if [[ -e ${files[0]} ]]; then
    numfiles=${#files[@]}
    echo "$numfiles files found"
fi
```

Using *nullglob* for the entire script – might be okay in some cases, bad in others:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob

...

files=(*.html)
numfiles=${#files[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of HTML *files* (not folders, symbolic links, etc.) in the current directory, and, if greater than zero, abort:

```
if [[ $( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.html" | wc -l ) -gt 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Oh no, there are HTML files!" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: While newlines in file names will break the counter, they only *increase* it. Any match will increase the counter beyond 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.html
do
  if [ -f "$i" ] 
  then
     echo "Cannot run, html files in current directory"
     exit 1
  fi
done
```